# TCP Listening server in 9870 port. Is it possible to configure the clients port?

Tags: tcp, tcplistener

When we open a TCP Listening, we use a fixed port, like "9870".
But the clients which connect to this listening, use different ports like "1024, 1025" or other. I don't know what is the name of this port, "client port", "dynamic port" or "ephemeral port"... But I need to know if is possible to change this client port.
Because, like in the second image, it shows the error "Port numbers reused", and I think this is related to this port configuration.

I think if I could configure these ports, the connections of the equipments on my network will be stabilized.

[image: netstat]

[image: WireShark error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;TR: there is usually no need to configure the clients source ports and you can definitely not set the clients source port at the server.

The client can bind to a address+port the same way the server can do and this port is then used as the source port for the connection. But usually this is not done and instead the socket is not specifically bound and a free source port is automatically assigned by the system. The client source port can  only be set by the client itself and can not be changed by the server.

Usually it is not possible that a port number gets reused by the client since the OS will not let the client do this. But what you see can happen if the client crashes . After the restart the client is not aware of any connections which were established (and never closed) before the reboot so it will happily use the same source port again. In this case it gets a RST from the server since the new data do not match the old connection.

This can also happen if the client is connected with some router doing NAT and the router crashes. After restart the router is not aware of any previous connections and will thus create new translations which might conflict with old connections.

Comment: In this solution I there is so much problem about disconnection, but I think it is related to another thing. (https://www.dropbox.com/s/mnkbbb2gogpbczb/Capturar.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: @BrunoYuzo: I have no idea what you are trying to tell me with this picture. Although one says that a picture is worth a thousand worth I would have preferred that many words which actually describe the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the poor information, in this picture there is a TCP listening opened by the "HostAcesso.exe" in port 9870. And the equipments connected in this listening is opening and closing the connection frequently. I though the problem was related to the Client Port, but by your explanation, probably it is another thing.

Comment: This connection is very strange, sometimes the same equipment connects two times but with client port different:

[192.168.0.70:9870 --- 192.168.0.172:1024]
[192.168.0.70:9870 --- 192.168.0.172:1025]

http://i.stack.imgur.com/HtLsh.jpg

Comment: @BrunoYuzo: if this is strange or not depends on the (unknown) use case. For example it is perfectly normal the a single client has multiple TCP connections open to a web server.

Comment: The error was solved, it was an electrical installation issue. Another equipment was sending voltage back to my equipment, and my equipment was resetting intermittently. Thank you for your effort.